# Want x,y coordinates of click within SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a map background, drawn as an SVG element with a width of 2188 pixels and a height of 1312 pixels.  I want the x,y coordinates of a click within this area, but the event clientX and clientY attributes, as well as the screenX and screenY attributes, seem to be scaled differently.  In both cases, the width and length are expressed as smaller quantities (apparently larger measurement units).

Can one retrieve the x and y coordinates of a click inside an SVG element that has a specified width and height?  I would also be willing to use a multiplier for clientX/Y or screenX/Y, but I do not understand what they denote.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>RESA Graphics</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
    <style>
        #svgContainer {
            width:  2188px;
            height: 1312px;
            background-color: "white";
        }
    </style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fixed.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='var.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload="resagui()">
    <div id="svgContainer"></div>
</body>
```

and here is JavaScript that defines attributes of the SVG element representing the map:

```
function resagui() {
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var boxWidth = 2188;
var boxHeight = 1312;

var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
svgElem.appendChild (g);
g.setAttributeNS (null, "transform", "translate(0.000000,1312.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)");
```

...

The scale in the last posted statement does seem fishy, but the difference does not seem to be a factor of 10.

Comment: if you are willing to use external library like d3.JS it helps you a lot. A lot of functionalities are built-in and very robust.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion to add markup to the question.  It has been updated.

Comment: The attributes pageX and pageY give the required results.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes pageX and pageY give the required results.